# How to filter with set analysis, sum and max, year and day

Tags: qliksense, qlik-expression

I'm trying to show the mount from last day loaded in the database (Filtering by year and date).

It will be like this:

```
Sum({$<ANO_MES={'$(=Max(ANO_MES))'},[SH_historico_1.DIA_PAGO]={19}>}[SH_historico_1.MONTO]/1000000)
```

The `"19"` have to be with code automated, and not manually.

So if I put:

`[SH_historico_1.DIA_PAGO]={MAX([SH_historico_1.DIA_PAGO])}` instead `"19"`

It will not load. So, how can I filter correctly?

I can show last day loaded "19" but with MAX, like this:

```
Max({$<[SH_historico_1.ANOMES]={'$(=Max([SH_historico_1.ANOMES]))'}>}[SH_historico_1.DIA_PAGO])
```

Any ideas? Any help it's welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put like this so it will evaluate first

```
[SH_historico_1.DIA_PAGO]={$(=MAX([SH_historico_1.DIA_PAGO]))}
```

or for example:

```
[SH_historico_1.DIA_PAGO]={"=$(=MAX([SH_historico_1.DIA_PAGO])")}
```

if it doesn't help you can also create variable with

```
MAX([SH_historico_1.DIA_PAGO]
```

and then put that variable to set analysis